# Get file downloaded from click in WebSession?

Tags: webdriver, websession, web-access

I'm downloading a file by clicking a button from chrome with the [WebDriver](http://workflow/ControlAWebBrowserProgrammatically) functionality:

```
sess = StartWebSession[Visible->True]
WebExecute[sess, "ClickElement" -> el] (* el is download button *)
```

This works just fine, and when it finishes it gives a success object:

```
Success["ClickElement",  Association[
 "MessageTemplate" :> "`command` was successful.", 
  "MessageParameters" -> Association["command" -> "ClickElement"], 
  "Element" -> "0.5797105527746262-24"]]
```

My question is two-fold:

1. I need a *file handle to the finished download* (and if it failed to download I need to know that).
2. Why doesn't it work *when session is not visible*. In particular, it gives success but doesn't actually download, for example:

```
sess = StartWebSession[Visible->False];
WebExecute[sess, 
 "OpenPage" -> "https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/Patient-Medical-Data-for-Novel-Coronavirus-COVID-19"];
a = WebExecute[sess, "LocateElements" -> "Tag" -> "a"];
p = Position[WebExecute[sess, "ElementText" -> a], 
   "Source Notebook"][[1, 1]];
WebExecute[sess, "ClickElement" -> a[[p]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `Import` straight on the file you want to download?

Comment: Import doesn’t work with JavaScript

Comment: But you are running it from Mathematica so what difference it would have if you use another Mathematica's function instead of `WebExecute`?

Comment: Import is highly restrictive with URL, it doesn’t work on anything async rendered.

Comment: ??? The `Import` worked pretty well for me with the file in your example "Patient-Medical-Data-for-Novel-Coronavirus-COVID-19-definition.nb". What problems do you have with it? You have also many different functions for downloading like `URLDownload` or `URLDownloadSubmit` and others. Give me an example when these functions and `Import` do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding that your code does not work with `StartWebSession[Visible->False]` seems to be a bug.

Here is my code that works with `StartWebSession[Visible->False]` but uses `URLDownloadSubmit` instead of `WebExecute`. If everything goes OK and the file is downloaded you get no message, if the file does not exist or something goes wrong you get a warning message. You can specify your own name of downloaded file and its path instead of `"C:\\file.nb"`. So this answer both of your questions.

```
sess = StartWebSession[Visible -> False];
WebExecute[sess, 
  "OpenPage" -> 
   "https://datarepository.wolframcloud.com/resources/Patient-Medical-\
Data-for-Novel-Coronavirus-COVID-19"];
a = WebExecute[sess, "LocateElements" -> "Tag" -> "a"];
p = Position[WebExecute[sess, "ElementText" -> a], 
    "Source Notebook"][[1, 1]];
URLDownloadSubmit[
 WebUnit`Private`attribute[
   sess /@ {"SessionID", "Browser", "URL"}, a[[p]]["ElementId"], 
   "href"], "C:\\file.nb", 
 HandlerFunctions -> <|"ConnectionFailed" -> MessageDialog|>, 
 HandlerFunctionsKeys -> "StatusCode"]
```